# Difference between call by pointer and returning pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any difference calling by pointer or returning pointer in following code?
I just try to modify my struct and get the resutl.
Lest say I have a struct.

```
struct Address
{
  const char* name; // "Jim Dandy"
  int number; // 61
};

Address* Modifying2(Address* adr)
{
  adr->name="Long John2";
  return adr;
}
//or
void Modifying3(Address* adr)
{
  adr->name="Long2 John2";
 // return adr; no return
}
void print_addr2(const Address& r)
{
  cout << r.name << '\n'
  << r.number << ' ' << r.street << '\n';  
}
int main()
{
   Address jd =
    {
    "Jim Dandy",
    61
    };

   Address* jdPtr=&jd;
   Modifying3(jdPtr);
   print_addr(jdPtr);
   //or
   print_addr(Modifying2(jdPtr));

  return 0;
}
```

Result is same but Which one is more safe? I mean well defined?

Comment: Looks like it should do the same thing.

Comment: Please, do not use pointers, only smart pointers and user-friendly wrappers such as std::string and std::vector. Don't waste your time with "what pointer thingy is not UB?"

Comment: Besides the obvious that one function return a value and other does not, there's no real difference between the functions. I wouldn't consider one "safer" or more "well defined" than the other.

Comment: Returning a pointer is only needed if you are going to change the pointer, or basically return a different pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are doing the same thing. Returning the pointer is not essential.

But the most safest way is to pass the value by reference. (You haven't implement this way). Here how you must do it

```
void Modifying4(Address &adr)
{
  adr.name="Long2 John2";
}
```

Comment: Good advice. There's no need to ever pass `nullptr`, so why even allow it?

Comment: @MSalters what you mean?

Comment: @DonCarleone: The main difference between a `T&` and a `T*` argument is that the `T*` argument will accept a pointer to an object or a `nullptr`, whereas the `T&` accepts only a reference to an object. That implies that a function accepting a `T*` should check if it got a `nullptr`. Exceptions: internals of smart pointer classes, overloads of algorithms normally taking iterators.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to return a pointer in the above example is if you want to allow chaining of calls:

```
Modifying2(Modifying2(jdPtr));
```

Which, for this particular implementation, does not make much sense since the function simply sets a value to a constant.

In all other cases, returning `void` is probably preferable, as you do not gain anything by returning the very same pointer that was passed in originally.

Comment: This chaining is bad style, as it suggests an order of modifications which is in fact inverted - the inner call is done before the outer call.

Comment: @MSalters Agreed, it's not something I'd write and I suppose it's probably also not what the author had in mind when deciding to return the pointer there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference. Both work.

But be careful with pointers! If you assign a string longer than the init-value, you have to realloc the space the pointer is pointing to!!!!

mfg

Comment: The pointers are used here only to point to string _literals_, so there is no need to reallocate anything. And if you're going to use strings for real, `std::string` will handle the reallocations for you.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a pointer after modifying the value it points to is redundant. 
In the real world other people, like us, or fellow coders in your company will be spending a lot of time in your code.

I forget who said it but you will also be spending 90% of your time pouring through someone else`s code.

If I saw your function that takes and returns a pointer at work I would be very confused why you did it, and it seems to show a lack of understanding of how pointers work and why you would pass a pointer to a function in the first place.

Don`t do it.